# Create aggregate variable in long data format

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm sure there's a question similar to this already, but I couldn't make them work

I am trying to calculate aggregates (or subtotals) in a dataframe of long format. In the group column I want an aggregate variable "AGG" that is a sum of "value" for a specific "Year" and "var". I have tried using the aggregate() function, but didn't succeed. I used the code:

```
aggregate(value ~ cbind(Year,var), data = Energi5, FUN = sum)
```

My data looks like this

```
> head(df)
     Year group  var     value
1    1966       A x   25465462
2    1966       B x    9512621
3    1966       E x    2832865
4    1966       H x     291769
5    1966      NE x  141524912
6    1966      NF x   23580353
> tail(df)
     Year group   var  value
5403 2017     NZ y    167158
5404 2017      O y     23480
5405 2017     QF y         0
5406 2017     QS y         0
5407 2017     QZ y     16447
5408 2017 TC3000 y    488556
```

and I would like to obtain something like this at the end of (or in the middle of) my existing dataframe

```
     Year group   var  value
5409 1966   AGG   x        ?
5410 1967   AGG   x        ?
...
5450 2017   AGG   x        ?
5451 1966   AGG   y        ?
...
```

I hope you can help. Thank you!

Comment: Do you use the `tidyverse` packages? Especially `dplyr::group_by()` and `dplyr::summarise()`? Here is an example: `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mean_width = mean(Petal.Width))` And [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#tidy-data-1) are some very usefull tips about data manipulations with R

Comment: What's your thinking behind using `cbind` there? That's making a matrix or data frame (not sure which by guessing)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but does this help?

```
library(dplyr)

df <- Energi5 %>%  group_by(Year, var) %>% mutate(value = sum(value)) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean))

df$group <- "AGG"

Energi5 <- merge(Energi5, df, all = T)
```

Comment: Why did you add a mean calculation?

Comment: I added it for aggregation. First the code summed the values per Year and var (mutate(value = sum(value)), but the dataset was still in long format. You can run the code without the %>% summarise_all(funs(mean)) to see what I mean.

Comment: But if the OP wasn't looking for a mean, why add it? You can just use `summarise` to get aggregated sums, instead of `mutate`

Comment: I don't know if it's the most efficient way, but it worked perfectly fine for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in how are you declaring the formula. See `?formula` in the manual.

```
# Example
year <- rep(seq(1966, 2020), each = 8)
group <- rep(letters[1:4], times = 2*(2021-1966))
var <- rep(c("x", "y"), times = length(year)/2)
value <- rnorm(length(year))

data <- cbind.data.frame(year, group, var, value)

# Solution
aggregate(value ~ year * var, data, FUN=sum)
```